# Searching in json array for parameter and show correct information

Tags: php, arrays, json

Is it possible to search inside json array which I pull with curl and if match to show only that data?

The array looks like

```
Array
(
[status] => success
[data] => Array
    (
        [out] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [address] => test address
                        [amount] => 11
                        [type] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [address] => test address 1
                        [is_nonstandard] => 
                        [amount] => 12
                        [type] => 1

                    )

            )
    )

[code] => 200
[message] => 
)
```

And this is how I pull the array

```
function get_curl_content_tx($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}
$url=get_curl_content_tx("http://example.com"); 
$total =json_decode($url,true);
```

So since there can be more that 1 arrays in `[out] => Array` as current situation they are two I want to search and match by `[address]` and when match to give data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it :

```
foreach($arr['data']['out'] as $d){
    if(strpos($d['address'], 'testaddress') !== false){
        //do something
        var_dump($d);
    }
}
```

You need to replace var_dump by whatever you want to do. 
I used strpos for the sake of this example, but you might want to use a custom method that would suits your needs better

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$outArray = $total['data']['out'];
foreach($outArray as $item) {
    // echo $item['address'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   if(isset($total['data']['out'])){
        foreach($total['data']['out'] as $out){
            if(isset($out['address'])){
                if($out['address'] == "your adress"){
                    //Your Stuff;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```